# How to have user_id inserted in a different table (no, not foregin key)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is currently my like table:

```
  Like Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes"
  +----+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
  | id | article_id | created_at              | updated_at              | user_id |
  +----+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
  | 1  | 1          | 2014-03-24 19:07:59 UTC | 2014-03-24 19:07:59 UTC |         |
  | 2  | 2          | 2014-03-24 19:18:59 UTC | 2014-03-24 19:18:59 UTC |         |
  | 3  | 4          | 2014-03-24 19:19:14 UTC | 2014-03-24 19:19:14 UTC |         |
  | 4  | 9          | 2014-03-24 19:47:36 UTC | 2014-03-24 19:47:36 UTC |         |
  +----+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+
  4 rows in set
```

As you can see, it's not filling in the user_id information when they like an article.

How do I fill in that information in the table above?

This is currently the like method in ArticleController:

```
  def like_vote
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.likes.create
   redirect_to(article_path)
  end
```

I'm kind of confused on figuring out how insert the user_id in the aforementioned method so, the Like table stores their user_id.

Help?

In case this is needed: this is the view

```
       <td><%= pluralize(article.likes.count, "like") %></td>
       <td><%= button_to '+1', "/articles/#{article.id}/user/#{current_user.id}/like_vote", method: :post %></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set up the `user_id`, for example:

```
@article.likes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer! it works. However, i have a question, if you don't mind. I'm really confused on `user_id: current_user.id` why does one have to write that whole thing out? I see that all the time, but I never quite get it. I mean, why can't just `current_user` work? Do you get my question?

Comment: When you create a new object, you just need pass the attributes to build the instance, in your case, a `Like` instance needs the `article_id`(auto set by `@article.likes.create`) and `user_id`(pass it as a parameter), that's all. This is the same: Like.create(article_id: @article.id, user_id: current_user.id)

Comment: so the way to pass it in the parameters is to put it in parenthesis?

Comment: Parenthesis are not really needed. You need to pass a hash (or an array of hashes to create multiple instances) with the parameters.

Comment: 'k! so, another way of passing current_user id could be `params[current_user.id]`?

Comment: Nops. Should be: `user_id: params[:user_id]`, but it's more secure to set the `user_id` fetching the value in the controller side.

Comment: why does one need to prefix it with `user_id:`? That's the other thing that always throws me off.

Comment: Because if you do: `Like.create(1,2)`; Rails doesn't know if `1` is the value for `user_id` or `article_id`, same for `2`. See with hash: `Like.create({user_id: 1, article_id: 2})` => one parameter (hash), explicit, regardless params order, `{}` can be omitted here

Comment: hm. ok. food for thought! =)

Comment: If you need more information, this is called in Rails `Mass Assignment`.